# IIS 7.5 FTP 550 Error for No Reason

Tags: android, iis-7, ftp

Before describing my problem, let me go into the configuration.

I bought an Android phone and thought that it would be a great idea to access my personal files at home on my Windows 7 Professional 64 bit computer from anywhere.

I setup IIS 7.5 to create an FTP site for my user directory (C:\Users\MyUser). Permissions are set to read-only for security reasons, since many of my personal files are publicly available (although password protected).

For several months now, it's worked wonderfully, allowing me to access photos, music, and even videos from my Android phone, over Wifi or through port forwarding, over 3G.

I've been working recently to organize my music better and consolidate it into one directory, so I've created/moved some directories around.

The organization scheme I have is Music\Band or Artist\Year - Album Title\Track Number - Song Title.mp3. It works well for organizing music on various flash-based MP3 players and phones.

Here is where the problem begins. This too, has worked wonderfully for the same amount of time until I got a few albums from a new band.

So, I create a few directories in the same organization scheme, but when I attempt to download them to my phone (and in other FTP programs) the last 7 (of 10) directories are listed, but cannot be downloaded, or files downloaded from. I get a 550 error that the file cannot be found, even though the server is able to list them. This occurs in two Android FTP programs, and two Windows based FTP programs connecting to localhost on the FTP server.

I checked the directories in the IIS Management snap-in, and they show as read-only access from my FTP user (which is the way I want it, as I mentioned). I've tried deleting, moving, and recreating them as well. I've restarted the computer and server, to no change in effect.

Did I miss something? Do changes in permissions need to be applied some other way?